# What is the exact difference between returning an IEnumerable instance and the yield return statement in C#

Tags: c#, ienumerable

Currently I'm working with some libraries applying deferred execution via iterators. In some situations I have the need to "forward" the recieved iterator simply. I.e. I have to get the `IEnumerable<T>` instance from the called method and return it immediately.

Now my question: Is there a relevant difference between simply returning the recieved `IEnumerable<T>` or re-yielding it via a loop?

```
IEnumerable<int> GetByReturn()
{
    return GetIterator(); // GetIterator() returns IEnumerable<int>
}
// or:
IEnumerable<int> GetByReYielding()
{
    for(var item in GetIterator()) // GetIterator() returns IEnumerable<int>
    {
        yield return item;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the advantage of re-yielding? If you want to perform some action on the items, you won't get around looping, right? If not, why not use the shorter-code-version?

Comment: I conclude from my experiments (and IL inspection), that the execution of GetByReYielding() will be deferred itself (independent of the way GetIterator() works), but the execution of GetByReturn() not. That's all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't any relevant difference (aside from *maybe* performance) between the two since you're not doing anything with the enumerator from `GetIterator()`. It would only make sense to re-yield if you were going to do something with the enumerator, like filter it.

Answer (score 4):

It may be worth your while reading Jon Skeet's article on C# Iterators.  It's quite informative.

http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter6/IteratorBlockImplementation.aspx

Answer (score 3):

They ARE different. For example, if the `GetIterator()` declared as:

```
IEnumerable<int> GetIterator() {
    List<int> result = new List<int>();
    for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        result.Add(i);
    }
    return result;
}
```

If you do not do re-yielding, the `GetIterator()` and the loop got executed immediately. Therefore, the answer depends on how you implement `GetIterator()`. If it is certain that `GetIterator()` will be yielding, so there is no point re-yielding it.

Comment: Even if he uses an iterator, it will still loop through the whole list before the first _yield_.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see there any relevant difference other than code bloating.

Answer (score 0):

There is a relevant difference.

The execution of GetByReYielding() will be executed in a deferred manner (as it is an iterator block). If you used a parameter in GetByReturn() or GetByReYielding() and checked that parameter at runtime for nullity (or did any other validation), this check would be done immediately when GetByReturn() is called but not immediately when GetByReYielding() is called! The validation in GetByReYielding() would be performed the deferred way, when the result is iterated. - This is often, well, "too late". See here:

```
// Checks parameters early. - Fine. The passed argument will be checked directly when
// GetByReturn() is called.
IEnumerable<int> GetByReturn(IEnumerable<int> sequence)
{
    if(null == sequence)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("sequence");
    }

    return GetIterator();
}
// Checks parameters in a deferred manner. - Possibly not desired, it's "too" late. I.e.                 // when the    
// result is iterated somewhere in a completely different location in your code the 
// argument passed once will be checked.
IEnumerable<int> GetByReYielding(IEnumerable<int> sequence)
{
    if(null == sequence)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("sequence");
    }

    for(var item in GetIterator()) 
    {
        yield return item;
    }
}
```

Mr. Skeet explained this concept in http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/09/03/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-2-quot-where-quot.aspx. The standard query operators provided in .Net use non-deferred wrapper functions (e.g. Where()) that check parameters and then call the core iterator function (as I showed in my implementation of GetByReturn()).

I hope this helps.